Basis of $V$ that contains a certain element $v$
I'm a student learning linear algebra.
Few days ago, I studied the concept of Gram-Schmit procedure in a given inner product space. With this procedure, if any $v \in V$ is given, then we can immediately construct its basis $B$.
Now I got curious about whether this is true for any vector spaces. Can we still construct a basis $B$ of $V$ such that contains the given $v \in V$?
I personally tried to prove it by assuming the AoC, but it didn't work though.

What do you mean its basis? You can choose any basis. Do you mean can you always choose an orthonormal basis? Or that a basis always exists?

@CyclotomicField Think I didn't mention it clearly. I wanted to ask whether we can always find a basis that contains a specific element of $V$.

Also, what do you mean by 'construct'? You assumed AC, and it looks like you are taking infinite-dimensional spaces into consideration. However, 'constructing' a basis itself is not a trivial question in many infinite-dimensional spaces, and certainly a basis cannot be constructed by the Gram-Schimidt procedure. Are you just trying to prove 'there exists'?

@Cyankite Sorry for that ambiguity. That's exactly what I meant to ask! Can we prove the existence of a basis that contains a specific element $v \in V$ for any vector space $V$?

For example, we can easily find such basis of 2d Euclidean space containing (1,2); {(1,2), (-1,1)}, {(1,2), (-1,0)}, etc.

You will need AoC, but use it in a slightly different way. That is, using transfinite induction. This is how we construct a basis step by step using ordinal numbers. So, by starting with the initial step $\{v\}$, we can construct a basis by extending this initial set.
An alternative way is that you accept the existence of a basis $B$. It may contain $v$, then we are done. If not, then write $v$ as a linear combination $v=a_1v_1+\cdots + a_kv_k$ with all $a_i$ are nonzero, $v_i$'s are members of your basis $B$. Then replace $v_k$ with your $v$. Then $(B-\{v_k\})\cup \{v\}$ is a basis containing $v$.
